# short Dump: Field symbol has not yet been assigned

Tags: abap

I am getting a short dump (Field symbol has not yet been assigned) when I run this program.
I know that I may get this error when I don't fill the `t_fieldcat` correctly.
As far as I know I have filled the field catalog correctly.

I cannot figure out where the problem is..Please help.

```
REPORT  Y_ALV1.

type-pools slis.
tables: scarr.

data:
      t_scarr type table of scarr,
      t_fieldcat type slis_t_fieldcat_alv.

data:
      wa_fieldcat type slis_fieldcat_alv.

select-options:
      s_carrid for scarr-carrid.

start-of-selection.
      select * into table t_scarr from scarr where carrid in s_carrid.
        if sy-subrc ne 0.
          leave list-processing.
          endif.

define fill_fieldcatalog.
  wa_fieldcat-col_pos = &1.
  wa_fieldcat-fieldname = &2.
  wa_fieldcat-tabname = &3.
  wa_fieldcat-outputlen = &4.

  append wa_fieldcat to t_fieldcat.

  end-of-definition.


  fill_fieldcatalog 1 'carrid' 't_scarr' 10.
  fill_fieldcatalog 2 'carrname' 't_scarr' 10.

  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISPLAY'
   EXPORTING
      IT_FIELDCAT                    = t_fieldcat
    TABLES
      T_OUTTAB                       = t_scarr
   EXCEPTIONS
     PROGRAM_ERROR                  = 1
     OTHERS                         = 2
            .
  IF SY-SUBRC <> 0.
 MESSAGE ID SY-MSGID TYPE SY-MSGTY NUMBER SY-MSGNO
         WITH SY-MSGV1 SY-MSGV2 SY-MSGV3 SY-MSGV4.
  ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the case does matter here. Change the following lines:

```
fill_fieldcatalog 1 'carrid' 't_scarr' 10.
fill_fieldcatalog 2 'carrname' 't_scarr' 10.
```

to

```
fill_fieldcatalog 1 'CARRID' 't_scarr' 10.
fill_fieldcatalog 2 'CARRNAME' 't_scarr' 10.
```

Comment: I wonder, it probably is good practice to also upper case the table name.

Answer (score 1):

Other option would be to do the translation to upper case in your macro. That way you can never make a mistake when calling it.

```
wa_fieldcat-fieldname = &2.
TRANSLATE wa_fieldcat-fieldname TO UPPER CASE.
wa_fieldcat-tabname = &3.
TRANSLATE wa_fieldcat-tabname TO UPPER CASE.
```